# frames surrounded by a rectangle in pgfmorepages

Tags: beamer, frame

I have the following simple code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
Nice to see you
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bye}
Nice seeing you
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

working quite well. But I would like to have each of my two frames be surrounded by a rectangular black box. I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}` option to add a line around the pages. Some viewer have some problems to draw this together with the background, for these cases you can switch off the background via `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}`

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfmorepages}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
Nice to see you
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bye}
Nice seeing you
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks indeed for reminding me of this simple trick.

Comment: @Denis You're welcome!